# Taxonomist badge for Topic proposals

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, documentation

When you create a tag that's used by users in Q&A, you receive the [taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge.

Similarly, 5 people have to commit to a tag proposal before it becomes a tag.

Those 5 people should earn a taxonomist-like badge for committing to a tag that gets X positive score examples.

Comment: Do we need more incentive to create tags for documentation? Seems like we have plenty of proposals, some of which are ridiculous (A [`date`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/date) tag? What would it document?). Maybe once the gold rush has died down.